# Android LinearLayout to align contents into different sides

Tags: android, layout

I'm still beginner at different Android layouts. Here is simple linear layout:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bt_template"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_template_button"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:background="#ffffffff"
            android:contentDescription="Choose template"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bt_captureImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_camera_button"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:background="#ffffffff"
            android:contentDescription="Choose template"/>

        <Button
            style="@style/MyRedButton"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:text="@string/str_new_mail_activity_button_send"
            android:id="@+id/bt_send" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

I want 2 buttons to go left and third button go right. How do I do that?

[image]

Blue buttons need to be on left side and red button on right side. How can I do that?

Comment: why dont you use relativelayout?

Comment: Try using a RelativeLayout inside the LinearLayout. Put your Buttons inside the RelativeLayout, align their sides to each other end give left/right margin to them. Or you can simply just align red button to the right side of the RelativeLayout, and other buttons to the left, next to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a possible option for using `LinearLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:contentDescription="Choose template"
        android:id="@+id/bt_template"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_template_button" />

    <ImageButton
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:contentDescription="Choose template"
        android:id="@+id/bt_captureImage"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_camera_button" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        style="@style/MyRedButton"
        android:id="@+id/bt_send"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/str_new_mail_activity_button_send" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you must use LinearLayout, give the red button a weight of 1 (so it will hog space) and make sure it has a gravity to the right if that's what you need.

```
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_gravity="right"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/bt_template"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:contentDescription="Choose template"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/bt_captureImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/bt_template"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:contentDescription="Choose template"/>

    <Button

        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="send"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/bt_send" />

</RelativeLayout>
```